# Pesquisa SQL entre duas tabelas com resultado duplicado

Tags: mysql, sql, query, oracle

Tenho uma View e uma tabela. A View `V_CUSTOMER` com dados dos clientes, mas não possue o CPF/CNPJ dos mesmos que na view, que é identificado pelo campo `V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID` que faz o relacionamento com a tabela `BUSINESSDATA_1SAT.CUSTOMER` e o campo `ID` do mesmo.

```
Select
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME,
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_PHONE_2,
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_SURNAME,
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TYPE,
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_STATUS_ID,
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID,
         businessdata_1sat.pkg_enc.decrypt_text(businessdata_1sat.customer.reference_number_enc, businessdata_1sat.customer.reference_number_iv) ref_num_CPF_CNPJ
     From
         V_CUSTOMER,
         businessdata_1sat.customer
     Where
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TYPE <> 'Técnico' And
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_STATUS In ('Ativo', 'Pendente') And
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_PHONE_2 Is Not Null and
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID IN (Select
            cus.id as customer_id
        From
            BUSINESSDATA_1SAT.CUSTOMER cus
        WHERE
            V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = cus.ID)
```

No segundo Select consigo filtrar os IDs de um com o outro.

O resultado me dá os Customers repetidos e vários CPF com resultados diferente e é campo único:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver esta Query?

**Informações adicionais**

Cada Customer_id é único e possui um CPF único. A instrução a Seguir, me mostra o ID do customer e o CPF do mesmo, todos são únicos.

```
select cus.id as customer_id, businessdata_1sat.pkg_enc.decrypt_text(cus.reference_number_enc, cus.reference_number_iv) ref_num_CPF_CNPJ
from businessdata_1sat.customer cus
where cus.id = 10;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: e o ref_num_cpf_cnpj que muda pra cada linha... vai colocar onde ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Preciso que seja uma coluna a mais, mas só referente ao customer, que também é único...

Comment: mas se os dados são diferentes, tem que exibir um por linha... e não dá pra ter mais linhas em uma só coluna... você pode até agregar todas as linhas em apenas uma celula... mas tem que saber se é isso q precisa

Comment: Aparentemente você esperava que sua tabela BUSINESSDATA_1SAT.CUSTOMER tivesse um único registro para cada valor de V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID, o que não parece ser o caso.

Comment: Editei a questão, não entendo porque a repetição com valores diferentes. Na pergunta melhorei.

Comment: Não me parece que esta saída corresponda à query postada já que na query existe o filtro `where cus.id = 10` e na saída apresentada existem múltiplos valores de `cus.id as customer_id`, inclusive 10 não é um deles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está nessa linha de código:

```
 V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID IN (Select
            cus.id as customer_id
        From
            BUSINESSDATA_1SAT.CUSTOMER cus
        WHERE
            V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = cus.ID)
```

Em nenhum momento antes na consulta você está cruzando as tabelas, apenas nesse **SUBSELECT**, no caso eu reescreveria a consulta de forma mais clara utilizando o **INNER JOIN**, mas respondendo a sua pergunta no caso você está trazendo todos os cpf e cruzando com todos que existem (**IN**) nesse **SUBLECT**.

Cruzando os dados no lugar mais recomendado no **INNER JOIN**, você evita dores de cabeça, segue a consulta ajustada:

```
Select
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME,
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_PHONE_2,
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_SURNAME,
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TYPE,
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_STATUS_ID,
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID,
         businessdata_1sat.pkg_enc.decrypt_text(businessdata_1sat.customer.reference_number_enc, businessdata_1sat.customer.reference_number_iv) ref_num_CPF_CNPJ
     From
         V_CUSTOMER        
     -------------------------------------------
     --FORMA RECOMENDADA DE CRUZAR TABELAS
     INNER JOIN businessdata_1sat.customer cus
       ON V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = cus.ID
     -------------------------------------------  
     Where
       V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TYPE <> 'Técnico' And
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_STATUS In ('Ativo', 'Pendente') And
         V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_PHONE_2 Is Not Null
```

Comment: deu certo. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o Join

```
Select * 
from V_CUSTOMER,
join businessdata_1sat.customer on V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = 
     businessdata_1sat.customer.cus.id
Where
     V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TYPE <> 'Técnico' And
     V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_STATUS In ('Ativo', 'Pendente') And
     V_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_PHONE_2 Is Not Null and
```